# Rotating multiple objects to specific centre axis

Tags: modeling

Hi Blender Forum (happy new creative year to all)

I'[image]m trying to rotate these 3 objects, on a 45 degree angle all at once. I couldn't figure out how to do so, so I did them one by one. So how's it possible to rotate multiple objects simultaneously. I know about individual origins, but I couldn't get the result I was after.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but maybe try positioning your 3D cursor where you have the red dot in your paint over and then rotate around that with all objects selected and set to individual origins.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for replying to my question. 

I have tried to do that, but even with individual origins, they go the same direction.I need to get them leaning towards the centre of of the cursor. Below is the tutorial Im following, the instructor is doing each leg one by one, but Im sure there is a quicker way to achieve this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuyHco6rhAc

at the 8:00 min he starts position the legs, this will give you a good insight what I'd rather want to achieve, than doing each leg one by one. Hope this helps you understand what technique Id like to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in the other answer you should probably used Linked-Duplicates(Alt+D) for this, I wouldn't recommend rotating the cylinder in edit mode like in the tutorial vid just position one cylinder in object mode while retaining it's transform info.

Make your cylinder and put it's origin at the cap of the object where it will be connected to the mics base, go into edit mode and select the top face of your cylinder position the 3D cursor there and set that as the origin point while in object mode now rotate the cylinder in place and position it how you like.

[image]

[image]

Then select the mic base and set the 3D cursor to it's center we'll use this as your rotation point, in top ortho view in the 3D view panel set your transformations to "Global" and the pivot to "3D cursor" select the cylinder and hit Alt+D then R to rotate the duplicate into position then simply hit Shift+R to repeat that operation for the third.

[image]

If you want to unlink the objects later go to the object menu > Relations > Make Single User > Object + Data

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris, it worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

You can Duplicate-Link the poles and rotate the original pole **in edit mode**:

- Start with one pole. Press Alt+D to make the other poles (make sure it's **Alt+D, and not** Ctrl+D)
- Go in top view and rotate each of the two other two poles **in object mode** by 120 degrees each
- Select the original pole and go into **edit mode** and rotate it towards the red dot in your pic.

Note that whatever **edits** you do to one pole, it happens to the other poles, but not in **object mode**.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, both replies I received were helpful, I managed to achieve good results doing it 2 different ways.

Kind Regards.