# How do I create multiple copies of an object around a point? (9 sided symmetry)

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

So I'm trying to create multiple copies of an object spaced equally around a ring. The goal is for it to look something like this, but I'm drawing a blank on how to accomplish it (I'm fairly new to blender).

The closest I've gotten is by using an array modifier with object offest and then rotating the object, they're actually in a circle, but as you can see they're not overlayed on the ring and individually they're all in the wrong orientations as they should be pointing in towards the centre.

[image: I want the selected objects to appear spaced evenly around the ring]
[image: This is basically the closest i've gotten as they're actually in a circle, but as you can see they're not offset where I want them and individually they're all in the wrong orientations]
[image: I want to acheive this effect of the chevrons being spaced equally around the ring and pointing inwards]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80298/how-to-add-numbers-to-a-dial/80300#80300

Comment: Thanks for the replies - This did what I was looking for https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162489/139899